# Resolve custom rxjs Subject in Angular template using async pipe

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, behaviorsubject

I have a custom BehaviourSubject in my Angular app, that is used as an Observable in my template.

When I call next on the Subject I expect the Subject in the template to be resolved. I use the `async` pipe to listen to asynchronous changes in this Subject.

I created an example in Stackblitz to show the problem that I have: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kmou5e

In `app.component.ts` I created an example asynchronous method, that sets a value to `this.data` after a timeout. As soon as `this.data` is set, `hello.component.ts` is initialized and rendered. I listen to `OnChanges`in `HelloComponent` and call `next()` on the custom Subject within `HelloComponent`.

As you can see in the template of `HelloComponent` I expect the observed Subject `customSubject$` to be rendered as an `<h1>` as soon as is gets a value through `next()`.

You can see, that the subscription of the `customSubject$` is called, as shown in the logs. Only the template doesn't render this Observable/Subject.

**How can I get the template to render when using a custom `Subject`? Do I need to use a different pipe?**

*FYI: I also tried to assign the value of the Subject to a new Observable using combineLatest, but it didn't work as well.*

Comment: Change `new Subject()` to `new ReplaySubject(1)` or `new BehaviorSubject()`.  https://www.learnrxjs.io/subjects/behaviorsubject.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a timing issue. Just change your Subject to a Behavior Subject (which caches the last emitted value) and your template will display the latest emitted value.

[image]

Here is a [good resource](https://medium.com/@luukgruijs/understanding-rxjs-behaviorsubject-replaysubject-and-asyncsubject-8cc061f1cfc0) on the various types of subjects.

Comment: Changing the Subject to BehaviorSubject helped:
`customSubject$: BehaviorSubject = new BehaviorSubject('initial value');`

Answer (score 1):

Very good question. The problem with this is the order of [lifecycle hooks](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks) Subject does not hold values, it just multi-casts to subscribers if there aren't any tough luck. Now life cycle runs in this order. Constructor, ngOnChanges, OnNgInit ..... then it loads the views and child components. So for you to see this value you need to buffer it by using a BehaviorSubject.

To see what I am talking about

```
import { Component, Input, OnChanges, SimpleChanges } from '@angular/core';
import { combineLatest, Observable, Subject } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'hello',
  template: `<h1>{{ customSubject$ | async }}</h1>
             <h2>{{test}}</h2>
  `
})
export class HelloComponent implements OnChanges  {
  @Input() name: string;
public customSubject$: Subject<string>;

    public test ='Before ngOnChanges run';

  constructor() {
      console.log('constructed');

    this.customSubject$ = new Subject();
    this.customSubject$.subscribe(s => {
      console.log('customSubject$ subscription resolved with ' + s);
    });
  }

  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
    if (changes.hasOwnProperty('name')) {
      console.log('ngOnChanges is called with ' + this.name);
      this.customSubject$.next(this.name);

    }
          this.test ='After ngOnChanges Ran';
  }
}
```

You have a test variable its value is changed in ngOnChanges. You will never get a glimpse of the value 'Before ngOnChanges run' because the view was not initialized yet.

Now your `*ngIf='data'` is confusing you further because the component is not constructed before ngIf resolves to true

It helps to increase your delay to see this

```
  ngOnInit() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.data = 'some string';
    }, 5000);
  }
```

Comment: Thank you for your very good answer, this exaplains a lot. I can't see in your example how you create the BehaviorSubject, tough.

Comment: I didn't create it. I was merely showing how "Before ngOnChanges run" will never be displayed and how the constructor will execute after the delay runs out. Just replacing subject to BehaviorSubject solves the issue because it buffers the last value. If you push two values the first one will be lost in this situation I was explaining so tomorrow we don't get the same question with BehaviorSubject and 2 messages